# How to make /private/etc/hosts available on macOS Sierra?

Tags: network, safari, macos, google-chrome, dns

After searching related questions and answers, I find my issue still unsolved: editing **/private/etc/hosts** does not work on **macOS Sierra**.

What in my /private/etc/hosts is the following two rules.

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   www.yahoo.com
```

These two rules cannot be applied in Safari and Chrome, even after running the command `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder`. The website yahoo is not redirected to 127.0.0.1.

So what do I miss in the above operation?

And the output of `ping -c 3 www.yahoo.com` is as following.

```
PING fd-fp3.wg1.b.yahoo.com (116.214.12.74): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 116.214.12.74: icmp_seq=0 ttl=47 time=138.418 ms
64 bytes from 116.214.12.74: icmp_seq=1 ttl=47 time=74.284 ms
64 bytes from 116.214.12.74: icmp_seq=2 ttl=47 time=69.702 ms

--- fd-fp3.wg1.b.yahoo.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 69.702/94.135/138.418/31.369 ms
```

Comment: Add `127.0.0.1 qwertyuiop` and try accessing `qwertyuiop` from the browsers and ping to determine if it's a priority/cache problem or the file is ignored completely.

Comment: @techraf I update /private/etc/hosts according to your suggestion, but cannot visit `qwertyuiop` in browsers. The output of `ping qwertyuiop` is like this: `PING qwertyuiop.dhcp (218.205.57.154): 56 data bytes` and `Request timeout for icmp_seq 0`. It looks like that `127.0.0.1` is redirected to `218.205.57.154`.

Comment: @waleking Please check the file /etc/hosts with `ls -la /etc/hosts`. It should show something like this: `-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  - 214 29 Aug 22:30 /etc/hosts` (with a different size - here 214 bytes - and date of course). If the file doesn't exist or can't be found, a suffix was added probably...

Comment: @klanomath yes, the output shows the file `/etc/hosts` exists: `-rw-r-----  1 root  wheel  71 Jan 10 13:50 /etc/hosts`. But this file does not work.

Answer (score 2):

If you can ping your /etc/hosts entries as root but not as regular user then try changing permissions on the hosts file to allow everyone to read. This worked for me.

```
sudo chmod a+r /etc/hosts
```

Comment: Yes, it works for me after I use your command and reboot my mac. Thanks so much, it puzzled me for a long time.

Comment: On 10.13.6, ping uses the hosts file address, but Safari and Firefox still get DNS from the outside.